# What is the average transaction time on the Stellar network?

Tags: transactions

In other blockchains, such as Bitcoin or Ethereum, the transaction time is limited by the block time. Even then, there's no guarantee your transaction will be incorporated into the next block.

How quickly should I expect to be able to perform a transaction on the Stellar network? What are the upper and lower bounds for the transaction time?

Answer (score 4):

Average ledger time for Stellar network is 4-5s, live network stats are available [here](https://dashboard.stellar.org/). So you can expect that your transaction will be processed within 5s time interval. In case of activity spikes, the transaction may be included into the next ledger.

Comment: A few more concrete stats from Kin's load tests: https://medium.com/kin-contributors/stellar-load-testing-results-for-the-kin-ecosystem-64c4d8676e69